# My audio plays fine before the 30 second mark, then stops, how can I adjust how long the audio goes for?

Tags: video-sequence-editor, audio

I cannot move a marker that cuts off my audio at the 30 second mark, how can I move it, or remove it?
[image: Audio plays fine until the 30 second mark]

Comment: Sounds like the option for having a separate frame range for the sequence editor and the whole scene. Don’t remember where that is, but pretty sure it’s a clock button somewhere on the open interface (not in any menus).

Comment: if Zarguls comment doesn't help, please provide blend file

Answer (score 0):

Select all strips(a) and then this:
[image]